# Telegram Bot: Send A message to multiple chat ids

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've been trying to send a message to multiple chat IDs using telegram bot

I've this code

```
from telegram import Bot, InputMediaDocument

BOT_TOKEN = "xxxxxx"
CHAT_IDs = [-1001xxx,-100177xxx,-100188xxx]

for CHAT_ID in CHAT_IDs:
  x
  x
  x
  bot.send_media_group(CHAT_ID, media=media_group)
```

The problem is message is only been sent to the last chat id in CHAT_IDs  array and skipping all infront

[I've referred this, but not much helpful]([Telegram BotApi, Send message to multiple chat_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418338/telegram-botapi-send-message-to-multiple-chat-id)

Comment: Are you sure your bot has a message going with those chatIds?

Comment: yes, is it better if i share full source ?

Comment: Yes, currently your code looks fine. You can log the response by Telegram why the message is not send

Comment: @0stone0 nothing wrong in response (response code:200)

Comment: It'll be very helpful, If someone could help me to figure this out